# model is not defined [node js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, model, routes

i dont understand what should i do when i have erorr "model is not defined" when i GET the data from the postman. i'm a newbie for node.js and javascript

my dir is:

```
app
--models
----user.js
model
--users.js
routes
--users.js
```

i've the app/models/user.js is:

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class users extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  };
  users.init({
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    phone_number: DataTypes.STRING,
    gender: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'users',
  });
  return users;
};
```

i've model/users.js is :

```
module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable('users', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER(5)
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(30)
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(50)
      },
      phone_number: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(15)
      },
      gender: {
        type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: true
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('NOW'),
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.fn('NOW'),
      }
    });
  },
  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable('users');
  }
};
```

and i've routes/users.js is :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', async function (req, res, next) {
  try {
    const users = await model.users.findAll({});
    if (users.length !== 0) {
      res.json({
        'status': 'OK',
        'messages': '',
        'data': users
      })
    } else {
      res.json({
        'status': 'ERROR',
        'messages': 'EMPTY',
        'data': {}
      })
    }
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({
      'status': 'ERROR',
      'messages': err.message,
      'data': {}
    })
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

i run the node server in the postman with GET, and my result is:

```
{
    "status": "ERROR",
    "messages": "model is not defined",
    "data": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### You have not import the model file in this file "routes/users.js

```
var model = require("./app/models/user.js");
```

Comment: Solution why after i export the models, the error is change to 

{"status":"ERROR","messages":"Cannot read property 'findAll' of undefined","data":{}}